# hazelcast what happened with IMap when server is crashed

Tags: java, spring, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

There are 2 nodes(**N1 and N2**) of hazelcast in embedded mode. Also there is an **IMap users** with 1 synchronous backup, others setting are default. Being in N1 i wanna get data(**users.get**) which are being in N2, but unfortunately when i'm doing that, N2 falls. Or N2 is crashed for 1-2 seconds earlier than i'll make call from N1.

1. What have i got as result of method users.get ?
2. Is N2 gonna be excluded from cluster in that case?
3. What is gonna happen if N2 becomes normal in 30 seconds?
4. Can you explain this algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

> What have i got as result of method users.get ?

You should get the matching value. Data should not be lost.

> Is N2 gonna be excluded from cluster in that case?

Even N2 is lost due to the crash or some other reason, you can access all your data. In this case, N2 will be out of the cluster.

> What is gonna happen if N2 becomes normal in 30 seconds?

N1 will detect N2 and they will form a cluster.

> Can you explain this algorithm?

You can read on mechanisms of [clustering](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#setting-up-clusters) and [re-partitioning](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#repartitioning).

Comment: thanks for answering.

but i don't understand where data will be got from? Let's imaigine that a user make request  to N1 to get data from the N2, N2 in that moment doesn't work for couple of sec and will start to work again in 3 seconds, where user get data in that case from? is it gonna be a request to the backup copy on the N1 without a re-partitioning or at first hazelcast will understand that N2 doesn't work trying to get data from N2 and will make user to wait while it to repartishing cluster and move data from backup to base memory and then will return data from it?

Comment: It will wait repartitioning but not necessarily migration. Readonly operations can return response during migration.